# Is there an easy way to reset P4 Client View (Command-line)?

Tags: perforce

I would like to make bash-script which resets the workspace completely (Removes files and client view). But so far I haven't found any command which removes all  the mappins in the client view - without having to manually delete the mappings from the file. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What's wrong with manually deleting the mappings from the file? I.e., `p4 client -o | grep -v '//depot' | p4 client -i` If this isn't what you're asking how to do, then you could perhaps clarify your question.

Comment: Thank you.. Nothing wrong with that. Just new to the p4 client interface, so didn't realize you could do it like that.
Can you mark a comment as a solution?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

p4 client -o | grep -v '//depot' | p4 client -i

Comment: Note that this only works if all your client mappings contain `//depot` (i.e. your only depot is the default `depot`) and it requires you to have `grep` installed (which is not default on all platforms)..

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you're allowed to save a blank client view, but here's how you'd do it:

```
p4 --field View= client -o | p4 client -i
```

From your description it sounds like you might want to actually just delete the client spec?  E.g.:

```
p4 revert //...
p4 sync #none
p4 client -d CLIENTNAME
```

Comment: "Invalid option --field"

Comment: Update your `p4` executable.  This is a 2016.1 client feature: https://www.perforce.com/blog/vcs/20161-command-line-roundup